# Illegal character VCHAR in request Header

Tags: integration, force.com-sites, error-messages, post

We have an external system that sends us POST Requests.

The authentication method is using force.com public site with IP restriction.

The external system sends a POST request and got an error and we found out that they sent a request with illegal char in the HEADER key ("@") and they get the response:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <title/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Bad Message 400</h1>
      <pre>reason: Illegal character VCHAR='@'</pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

They making a POST request to:
https://myDomain.force.com/service_That_Defined_In_The_Site/services/apexrest/Resource_Service_Name

So i know why this error message appears, which appears that "@" its illegal from **rfc2616** :

```
   token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
   separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
                  | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
                  | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
                  | "{" | "}" | SP | HT
```

But what I don't understand, is why I don't get any logs in my SF system about it.

I made all the logs as finest, (from the guest user and from the automated Process) just to know if they try to call the service, but I don't see a thing.

this is a message that SF is generated for a bad request in the Header? and blocks the request before it comes to my SF server? (like when trying to send a request from an unauthorized IP)

this is an HTTP issue that does not arrive in SF at all?

many thanks!