# Single Logout (SLO) API - 400 Bad Request - Illegal character VCHAR='='

Tags: post, curl, postman, logout

This is as part of Single Logout (SLO) implementation. The need is to logout Salesforce Experience Cloud Site when user logsout from java based application.

To implement this, below Salesforce endpoint is used with POST http method. The request CURL is mentioned below. When testing this in Postman, getting 400 - ***Illegal character VCHAR='='***

Please advise how to fix this.

> URL: https://env-comp.ab300.force.com/direct/services/auth/sp/saml2/logout

ERROR RESPONSE:

```
 <h1>Bad Message 400</h1><pre>reason: Illegal character VCHAR='='</pre>
```

REQUEST:

```
 curl --location 'https://env-comp.ab300.force.com/direct/services/auth/sp/saml2/logout' \
 --header 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7' \
 --header 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9' \
 --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
 --header 'Connection: keep-alive' \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 --header 'Origin: http://localhost:9000' \
 --header 'Pragma: no-cache' \
 --header 'Referer: http://localhost:9000/' \
 --header 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
 --header 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
 --header 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' \
 --header 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
 --header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
 --header 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"' \
 --header 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
 --header 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
 --header 'Host: env-comp.ab300.force.com' \
 --header 'Cookie: <Cookie-Info goes here>' \
 --data-urlencode 'RelayState=/direct/s' \
 --data-urlencode 'SAMLRequest=PVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDphc3NlcnRpb24iPnZhc2FudC5udWxsQGdtYWlsLmNvbTwvc2FtbDpOYW1lSUQ+PC9zYW1scDpMb2dvdXRSZXF1ZXN0Pg=='
```

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335035/illegal-character-vchar-in-request-header